# Alias dictionary in python, Class vs dict

Tags: python, alias

I want to keep a set of field names as aliases (like `'fieldName' = 'f'`) in my python project. While I'm pretty sure the most straight forward way is to just keep a dict, like

```
F = {'_id'         :       '_id',
     'tower'       :       'T',
     'floor'       :       'F',
     'pos'         :       'P'
     }
```

I am thinking I can just write a class, like,

```
class F:
    def __init__():
        self._id         =       '_id',
        self.tower       =       'T',
        self.floor       =       'F',
        self.pos         =       'P'
```

The sole reason is then I can access the data using,

`get_var(f._id)` which is shorter and nicer looking compared to,

`get_var(F['_id'])`

Is it abusing python if I do it? and is there any advantages or disadvantages?

These aliases will be read from a config file at startup and will not change through the running time.

---

EDIT:

From silas's answer, I cooked up this. Why would this be bad compared to your answer?

```
class Aliases:
    """ Class to handle aliases for Mongo fields. 
        TODO: Should these be read off from a config file?
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._F = {
            '_id'         :       '_id',
            'tower'       :       'T',
            'floor'       :       'F',
            'pos'         :       'P',
            'stabAmplitude'   :   's',
            'totalEnergy' :       'z',
            ...
        }

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """ Return the attributes from the alias dictionary instead of the 
            real attributes dictionary
        """
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, '_F')[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError('No attribute named %s.' % name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        """ No attributes should be changable """
        if name == '_F':
            return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
        else:
            raise AttributeError('Attribute %s cannot be changed.', name)
```

Comment: It's not "abusing" python per se, but if you only need the structure to store key-value pairs which aren't methods or stateful, then just use a dict. Don't make your code more complex to shave off a character or two when accessing elements from your object.

Comment: it's not about the char length. I feel like it looks ugly, since those names are in fact field names on a python dictionary (returned by `pymongo`). So a general query would look like `entry[F['_id']]` vs `entry[F._id]` I felt the former was confusing.

Answer (score 4):

What you are probably after (*not commonly used afaik*) is an **Attribute Dictionary**.

See: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrdict

Basic usage:

```
>>> from attrdict import AttrDict
>>> d = AttrDict({"id": "foo"})
>>> d.id
"foo"
```

If you'd really like some form of *aliased* attribute/dict-style access then the following *quick 'n dirty*) OO-style code subclassing `attrdict.AttrDict` will work:

```
from attrdict import AttrDict


class AliasedAttrDict(AttrDict):

    aliases = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self.__class__.aliases:
            return super(AliasedAttrDict, self).__getitem__(self.__class__.aliases[key])
        return super(AliasedAttrDict, self).__getitem__(key)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self.__class__.aliases:
            return super(AliasedAttrDict, self).__getitem__(self.__class__.aliases[key])
        return super(AliasedAttrDict, self).__getitem__(key)


class MyDict(AliasedAttrDict):

    aliases = {
        "T": "tower",
        "F": "floor",
        "P": "pos"
    }


d = MyDict({"tower": "Babel", "floor": "Dirty", "pos": (0, 0)})
print d.tower
print d.floor
print d.pos
print d.T
print d.F
print d.P
```

**Output:**

```
Babel
Dirty
(0, 0)
Babel
Dirty
(0, 0)
```

Comment: Will is right though. Just use an ordinary dictionary, there is hardly any advantage is shaving off a *single character* for lookups. But if you really need/want this, ``attrdict`` is the thing to use.

Comment: +1 for advocating pypi ad reusing of code! fight the nih-syndrom! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use a full configurable proxy object instead of a var name lookup table (seems like a half-measure to me).

```
class VarMapProxy(object):

    def __init__(self, proxied_call, **kwargs)
        self.call = proxied_call
        self.var_map = kwargs

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self.call(self.var_map[name])
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError('No attribute named %s.' % name)

fields = VarMapProxy(get_var, id='_id', tower='T', floor='F', pos='P')
fields.id # will return the result of get_var('_id')
fields.pos # will return the result of get_var('P')
```

Comment: I don't like this. a) it's not generic b) it's broken. This is not an good overall solution in it's current form ;/

Comment: I fixed the `return` I forgot.  I also modified it to be generic, and switched it from subclassing dict to containing a dict, which is really better, I think.  More generic as well.

Comment: And `def` instead of `class`... oi, must be time for me to go home.

Comment: I think it would be better if you re-worked your answer to just point to an existing ``Proxy`` implementation rather than re-inventing the wheel on this one :) -- But **Proxy Pattern** is another good solution in general IHMO.

Comment: Feel free to prove me wrong, but for a proxy this simple, any package is probably going to be over complicated, and any other solution is just going to be a recipe, which is pretty much what I have here.  :)

Comment: Challenge not accepted! :) Both solutions are just as valid :)

Comment: I dont understand the whole proxy thing, but I added something related to the question, would that be a good answer?

Answer (score 1):

Faster and maybe nicer than creating a class for this purpose - using namedtuple. It has the memory consumption of a tuple (I think) but it is easier to read/handle with named attributes instead of index-numbers

```
from collections import namedtuple

F = namedtuple("F", "tower floor pos")

f = F(tower=1, floor=2, pos=(1,4))
```

**Usage**

```
f.tower
Out[127]: 1

f.floor
Out[128]: 2

f.pos
Out[129]: (1, 4)
```